# Outdated Git version in OS X vulnerable to remote execution attacks

Tags: xcode, git, macos, security, osx-elcapitan

I am not using any source control repository but project was created with Git enabled as below:

[image]

**Will my machine will also be vulnerable to the remote execution attack.**

It seems an outdated version of Git on OS X exposes the system to remote code execution attacks.

http://www.networkworld.com/article/3058752/outdated-git-version-in-os-x-puts-developers-at-risk.html?token=%23tk.NWWNLE_nlt_networkworld_security_alert_2016-04-20&idg_eid=6f584fd7fd740b71552ec8212b825ee6&utm_source=Sailthru&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=NWW%20Security%20Alert%202016-04-20&utm_term=networkworld_security_alert#tk.NWW_nlt_networkworld_security_alert_2016-04-20

Note: Mac Machine is connected to Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Your question

> Will my machine will also be vulnerable to the remote execution
>   attack.

is kinda broad but you can of-course do these things to be on safer side

1. Update your git version([Latest2.8.1 here](https://git-scm.com/downloads))
2. Since you are not using any Source Control you can obviously stop tracking your project with git. Goto your project path in terminal and use the following command to remove git

   rm -rf .git

Comment: can't update to Git as its controlled by Apple. That is the issue as we can't upgrade it. I can try second option but my question is slightly different it asks if i am not using any repository but project has .git file, will my system be vulnerable.

Comment: you can update git manually by installing the new version 2.8.1 in your mac here https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: Apple doesn't gives permission to update that. Link specifically informs about the vulnerability on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using git *as a client* and you trust every person using your Mac, I would say that you face a pretty small risk.

In the described vulnerability for git clients, **a local user** could potentially execute arbitrary code, but this implies that the attacker already has access to your system as a local user. A successful exploit would need to trick you into executing git in a carefully crafted manner. As long as you only execute scripts and binaries from trusted sources, you should be fine.

On the other hand if you are hosting some kind of git "server", such as a public repository from your computer, that's a very different story.